# How to configure ansible for ssh connection with a user and specify root usage for per-host elevation?

Tags: linux, ansible, configuration

I'm a newbie to ansible and I'm using a very simple command.

```
ansible -i "client1," all -u mainteneur -b -K -m shell -a "whoami"
```

but I'd like to don't use the switches **-u** and **-K**, so I don't have to type the password.

If I use ansible.cfg, it's work but the password is not the same on all my clients.

```
[su_become_plugin]
user = root
executable = su
password = 'MyPass'
```

How to I use host's variable for ansible_ssh_user (**-u**) and ansible_become_password (**-K**) in configuration's file?

Here my inventory's file :

```
 all:
  children:
    linux:
      children:
        web:
          hosts:
            client1:
          vars:
            var1: "apache2"
            ansible_ssh_user: "mainteneur"
            ansible_become_password: "MyPass"
        db:
          hosts:
            client2:
              var1: "mariadb"
```

What am I doing wrong ?